# Empty output stream at AES decrypt. Reason?

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I trying to decrypt something and don't understand why I getting empty result. I don't getting any errors through. I think that's weird. Even if key is invalid then decrypted junk should be meaningless bytes, but not empty. I made minimal example.

```
Aes aes = Aes.Create();
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            aes.KeySize = 128;
            aes.Key = new byte[] { 0x5f, 0x4d, 0xcc, 0x3b, 0x5a, 0xa7, 0x65, 0xd6, 0x1d, 0x83, 0x27, 0xde, 0xb8, 0x82, 0xcf, 0x99 };
            aes.IV = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

            // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            string encrypted_str_b64 = "E1UinhOTTy8Sj/IxCPEM+UNhIpTXIXnOAUtPgA35erJmvRc22gsdvIgcMZORZ2SY";
            byte[] ecrypted_junk = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted_str_b64);

            string plaintext = string.Empty;

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(ecrypted_junk))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
                    {
                        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                        byte[] temp_buf = new byte[1024];
                        int read_bytes = cryptoStream.Read(temp_buf, 0, temp_buf.Length); //read_bytes = 0...
                        
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd(); //string is empty...
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: `FlushFinalBlock()` empties the stream, what else should be written? If you remove that, you will get a _CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed_, because data and key obviously don't match. By the way, you use a strange construct (but there may be a reason for this, of course): You first write into a 1024 bytes buffer (`temp_buf`) and then (if there is still something left) read the rest with `ReadToEnd()`. So if the data fits _completely_ into the buffer, nothing is read with `ReadToEnd()`, even in case of a successful decryption.

Comment: @Topaco - with that `buf` I just tested if I can read something from stream... And yes, I was getting `Padding is invalid and cannot be removed` exception at first, so added `FlushFinalBlock()` to avoid it, but never knew it will clear the stream... I don't understand what you mean by `data and key don't match`. Shouldn't I get meaningless bytes output in this case instead of exception?

Comment: _Data and key don't match_ should simply mean that the ciphertext was generated with a different key (otherwise the decryption would be successful). If PKCS7 padding is used and the decryption fails (e.g. because data and key don't match), data incompatible with PKCS7 will generally be produced at the end, leading to the observed exception. If you e.g. don't use padding when decrypting (`PaddingMode.None`) you will get meaningless bytes.

Comment: @Topaco - I think that's good enough to be an answer. Make it. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No data is decrypted because `CryptoStream` is empty when decrypting the data. This is because it was cleared with [`FlushFinalBlock()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.flushfinalblock?view=netcore-3.1) before the actual reading. According to the comment, `FlushFinalBlock()` was implemented because of the otherwise occurring padding exception, but this is no solution for the problem.

If the `FlushFinalBlock()` call is removed, a *CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed* is generated, indicating an error during decryption (e.g. typically when using a key that is not identical to the key used to generate the ciphertext).

The direct cause of the padding exception is that the decryption produces a wrong plaintext (consisting of meaningless bytes), which therefore produces an invalid [PKCS7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) at the end. If the decryption would be done without padding ([`PaddingMode.None`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode?view=netcore-3.1)), this exception would not be generated and the result would be indeed meaningless bytes.

So the *real* solution to the problem is to use the correct key, i.e. the key with which the ciphertext was created. Otherwise a decryption is practically impossible.

Just for completeness: The posted code uses a buffer (`temp_buf` ) that is implemented for testing purposes according to the comment. The data is written to this 1024 byte buffer with [`CryptoStream#Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.read?view=netcore-3.1). The rest is read with [`StreamReader#ReadToEnd()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend?view=netcore-3.1). If the data fits completely into the buffer, the 2nd part does not return any more data and thus returns an empty string, even in case of a successful decryption, which would not be an failure (with regard to the comment *//string is empty...* in the posted code).